# How to unit testing OidcSecurityService.checkAuth function with Jasmine?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, istanbul

I am using Jasmine for unit testing in Angular. And I am using the OidcSecurityService service for security. Now I want to unit test this piece for the automatic login:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'cityflows-client';
  constructor(public oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService, private router: Router, public platform: Platform) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.oidcSecurityService
      .checkAuth()

      .subscribe(isAuthenticated => {
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
          if ('/autologin' !== window.location.pathname) {
            this.write('redirect', window.location.pathname);
            this.router.navigate(['/autologin']);
          }
        }
        if (isAuthenticated) {
          this.navigateToStoredEndpoint();
        }
      });
  }
```

and so the unit test looks like this:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      providers:    [ {provide: OidcSecurityService, useClass: OidcSecurityServiceStub} ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }); 
});
```

And the stub looks like this:

```
export class OidcSecurityServiceStub {
  getToken() {
    return 'some_token_eVbnasdQ324';
  }

  checkAuth(url: string) {
    return of(url);
  }

  authorize(authOptions?: AuthOptions) {
    if (authOptions) {
      return authOptions.urlHandler('http://localhost');
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

But i see in the coverage report this:

by the if that the else part is not taken.

So what I have to change? Thank you

```
  it('should redirect user to login page if user is not logged in', () => {
    
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Comment: Has somebody any advice?

Comment: I dont see the image which you are referring as coverage report

Comment: which line you want to cover ? Can you circle it for better understanding

Comment: Yes, where both E is standing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to correct mockfile

```
export class OidcSecurityServiceStub {
  getToken() {
    return 'some_token_eVbnasdQ324';
  }

  checkAuth() {
    return of(true); // <-------- make it return true
  }

  authorize(authOptions?: AuthOptions) {
    if (authOptions) {
      return authOptions.urlHandler('http://localhost');
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

this would cover below code:

```
 if (isAuthenticated) {
          this.navigateToStoredEndpoint();
        }
```

now for `false`, use jasmine

```
  it('Navigate if not authenticated', () => {
    spyOn(component.oidcSecurityService,'checkAuth').and.returnValue(of(false));
    // also spy on write and router.navigate
    component.ngOnInit()
    expect(component.router.navigate).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/autologin']); // because the url will not be /authLogin (I am assuming, please correct accordingly)
    // similarly check for component.write()
  });
```

2. To check `if ('/autologin' !== window.location.pathname)` you need to override the `window` object to set the value accordingly in `pathName`

You can refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63897319/typeerror-failed-to-execute-createobjecturl-on-url-no-function-was-found-t/63907794#63907794)  where I mocked one of the `window` method. in You case you need to set `pathName` and test it