# Unable to spy on window.confirm()

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

In my Angular 8 project, on clicking on signout, a confirm window comes up and asks Yes/No to logout. I want to test whether the confirm window appears or not. In my `spec.ts`, I wrote `spyOn(window, 'confirm').and.returnValue(false);`. I don't know whether that is correct or not. I need two things. Firstly, whether the confirm window comes up or not; and secondly, how to click on the 'Yes' option using jasmine. Please help. Below is my code:

header.component.ts

```
...
import { AuthenticationService } from '../../core/authentication.service';
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
legalName: any;
constructor(public authService: AuthenticationService, public accountService: AccountService, public router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.accountService.getTransactionHistory().subscribe((res) => {
      res = JSON.parse(res);
      this.legalName = res['Result'].array.RevTrxn[0].trxn.legalName;
    })
  }

signout() {
    this.authService.signout();
  }
```

authentication.service.ts

```
signout(){
    var res = window.confirm("Are you Sure!")
    if(res){
      window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
      this.router.navigate(['/login'])
    } 
  }
```

header.component.spec.ts

```
import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/core/authentication.service';
import { AccountService } from 'src/app/core/account.service';
import transactions from 'src/app/core/model/mock-transaction-history.json';

describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;
  let debugElement: DebugElement;
  let mockAuthService;
  let mockAccountService;
  let trans;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    trans = transactions;
    mockAccountService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getTransactionHistory']);
    mockAuthService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['signout']);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HeaderComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: AccountService, useValue: mockAccountService },
        { provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: mockAuthService },
      ],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
  });

  it('clicking on "Sign Out" should ask user to confirm', () => {
    mockAccountService.getTransactionHistory.and.returnValue(of(JSON.stringify(trans)));
    const callSignOut = mockAuthService.signout.and.returnValue([]);
    spyOn(window, 'confirm').and.returnValue(false);
    const signOut = debugElement.query(By.css('.sign-out'));
    signOut.triggerEventHandler('click', {});
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(window.confirm).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

While running this, I am getting `Expected spy confirm to have been called.` in karma console. I don't know why it is not getting called. I have tested whether `signout()` function of `AuthenticationService` is getting called or not. It is getting called anyways. The `window.confirm()` method is inside the `signout()` function as you can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll put my feedback as an answer rather than a comment, reason being, your way of doing unit testing is slightly misleading.

The idea of unit testing is to isolate each file (service, component, pipe etc) and then test its functionality. To isolate , we use use mocks. I can see that you have done it perfectly.

Now, as a part of unit testing you should test whether `this.authService.signout();` is called on `signout()` . Whether the `authService.signout()` calls `windows.confirm` should be a part of unit test of `AuthenticationService`.

Coming to your question of testing `window` object (for your `service` which you should do), you need to create `serviceWindowObj` and assign `window` object to it. [I have covered similar question where I replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63897319/typeerror-failed-to-execute-createobjecturl-on-url-no-function-was-found-t/63907794#63907794) `window` object. Take a look at it. I think you can get an idea from that.

Cheers !

---

Since you are new to unit testing of Angular, try [this article](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7) which contains several more links at the bottom to help you out with best practices

Answer (score 1):

Is your service implementation really called during the test? You are injecting a service mock:

```
{ provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: mockAuthService },
```

Then in your test you mock the signout method:

```
const callSignOut = mockAuthService.signout.and.returnValue([]);
```

So on click, this would not call your service method as you require:

```
signout() {
    // This calls your mock service now.
    this.authService.signout();
}
```

On a general note: I would create a `WindowService` that returns the window object. This makes it a lot easier to mock the window during testing.